# Separate On first period R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I have a data frame where I am looking to separate a column (var) into 2 columns by the first ".". The values in var currently have 2 periods. I would like to call the new names "First" and "Second. I have added my data frame as well as a screen shot of it. At the end I show my attempt.

[image]

```
df = structure(list(Date.Dates = c("42370", "42373", "42374", "42375", 
"42376", "42377"), var = c("SHOP US Equity.30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF", 
"SHOP US Equity.30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF", "SHOP US Equity.30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF", 
"SHOP US Equity.30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF", "SHOP US Equity.30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF", 
"SHOP US Equity.30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF"), val = c("59.835999999999999", 
"67.208600000000004", "61.522599999999997", "63.298900000000003", 
"66.243200000000002", "69.282899999999998")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))


library(tidyverse)
df %>%
      gather(var, val, -Date.Dates) %>%
      separate(var, c("First", "Second", sep = "/^([^.]+)/"))
```

We should have a new column called "First" that holds the value "SHOP US Equity". A second column called "Second" that contains the value "30DAY_IMPVOL..."

Thank you

Comment: Do you really need the `gather` step there.  It is creating a column with both 'character/numeric' mix

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We can use `extract` to capture the characters that are not a `.` (`[^.]+`) from the start (`^`) of the string as a group, followed by the `.` (`\\.`) and the rest of the characters in second group for the "Second" column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>%
    extract(var, into = c("First", "Second"), "^([^.]+)\\.(.*)")
```

---

Or just use `[.]` as `sep`.  It would split into two columns with a warning as there are multiple `.` and this will split at the first occurence of `.`

```
df %>% 
     separate(var, into = c("First", "Second"), "[.]")
# A tibble: 6 x 4
#  Date.Dates First          Second           val               
#  <chr>      <chr>          <chr>            <chr>             
#1 42370      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100 59.835999999999999
#2 42373      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100 67.208600000000004
#3 42374      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100 61.522599999999997
#4 42375      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100 63.298900000000003
#5 42376      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100 66.243200000000002
#6 42377      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100 69.282899999999998
```

If we don't need the warningss, another option is to use a regex lookaround

```
df %>%
   separate(var, into = c("First", "Second"), "(?<=[a-z])\\.(?=[0-9])")
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df[c("First", "Second")] <- read.csv(text = sub("\\.", ",", df$var), header = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `str_split`/`str_split_fixed` from `stringr` where we can specify in how many parts we want to split the string (`n`). Since here we want only 2 columns we can specify `n = 2`.

```
stringr::str_split_fixed(df$var, "\\.", 2) %>%
        as.data.frame() %>%
       setNames(c('First', 'Second'))

#           First                    Second
#1 SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF
#2 SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF
#3 SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF
#4 SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF
#5 SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF
#6 SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF
```

Comment: as always, thank you @Ronak. I learn from all your posts. However, have decided to go with akrun answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `extra` parameter as shown below

```
df %>%
  separate(var, c("First","second"), "\\.",extra = "merge")
# A tibble: 6 x 4
  Date.Dates First          second                    val               
  <chr>      <chr>          <chr>                     <chr>             
1 42370      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF 59.835999999999999
2 42373      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF 67.208600000000004
3 42374      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF 61.522599999999997
4 42375      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF 63.298900000000003
5 42376      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF 66.243200000000002
6 42377      SHOP US Equity 30DAY_IMPVOL_100.0%MNY_DF 69.282899999999998
```